# Email validation error is not showing up on the View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I changed the code to the following and I am still not getting any validation error on the View.

*

```
<td>
                            <div class="col-xs-7">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonalEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonalEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                            </div>
                        </td>
```

*

I am adding an email validation to my model and testing on the View.

Here is my View

```
<tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%;"></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-xs-7">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonalEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

In my model, I have

```
 [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
        public string PersonalEmail{ get; set; }
```

I also tried this

```
[Display(Name = "Email address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string PersonalEmail{ get; set; }
```

When the View is rendered, I typed in 'Test' or 'test.com' but no validation error appears. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your forget validationmessage in there

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PersonalEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `ValidationMessageFor`:

```
<div class="col-xs-7">         
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @id = "textEmail", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "email@example.com" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using @Html.EditorFor and in model adnotations [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]